# how do I load partial pages in lightbox using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, lightbox, partial

thanks for coming in and looking at my question.

I have a page that has a bunch of dynamic a tags with ids like aTag1, aTag2 ans so on.

now I need to make these tags open the same lightbox that initially loads a partial page named register.php, 
and the user will fill out the form, sumbit it then go to another partial page named payment.php and go on until the registration and payment are all settled.

this process needs to be done using ajax.

I think this should be relatively easy if appropriate ajax plugin is used.

Could you please advise any plugins and tips?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). Of particular interest to you would be the [modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) demo. If you definitely need to have the content loaded from separate URLs, you could put an iframe in the dialog or do something like [this example](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/06/load-page-dynamically-inside-jquery-ui.html).